# After added splash screen, MainActivity Occur error and force to close apps

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

**Splash Screen**

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = ProductFragment.class;
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initNavigationDrawer();
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hong.user.healthyfx">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Error in logcat**
03-28 11:20:22.921 11653-11653/com.hong.user.healthyfx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.hong.user.healthyfx, PID: 11653
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hong.user.healthyfx/com.hong.user.healthyfx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:380)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:430)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:421)
                                                                             at **com.hong.user.healthyfx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)**
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Line 42 in MainActivity:
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

May I know where is my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: Can you make sure your fragment is not null as you expecting to get exception in fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance(); and if there is exception so your fragment will be null and you are pushing the null fragment in stack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: show your xml layout where fragment container is being defined.  You must make sure you initialized the container before using it within the replace method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code in MainActivity to:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, new ProductActivity()).commit();
}
```

For best readability you need rename

```
ProductActivity
```

to

```
ProductFragment
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your activity `OnCreate()` method as:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

       Fragment  fragment = new ProductActivity(); // Change fragment class name to ProductFragment

       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }
    .........
    ..............
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in your code:-

It is your MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        //How can you provide activity class for fragment initialization and push it in fragment stack.
        Class fragmentClass = **ProductActivity.class**;
        //It supposed to be fragment class not Activity.

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initNavigationDrawer();
}
```

Comment: sorry, actually my productActivity is extends Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = ProductActivity.newInstance();
        //How can you provide activity class for fragment initialization and push it in fragment stack.


        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }
```

Comment: sorry, actually my productActivity is extends Fragment.